# node_modules folder missing after push to git remote repo

Tags: node.js, git

Has anyone faced the problem of missing **node_modules** directory or any other dir after pushing to remote git repo?

I just did a **git push origin master** yesterday and can't find node_modules directory on my local repo since then.

I have the package.json file in my project dir, so I can just do **npm install** to get the modules back but wondering why it got deleted at all.

For more info, I have node_modules ignored in **.gitignore** file along with few others but I can see other ignored files present still in my project dir except node_modules. Anything I'm missing which can cause this? I did backup of my project dir just before pushing it to remote and can see node_modules dir present there.

Comment: It is correct that node_modules is in .gitignore. DO NOT attempt to push it to your git repository because it is too large, and some packages might need compiling from the machine you're executing `npm install`. As for the other files in .gitignore that appear in your local repo folder, perhaps they are meant to be configs or "uploaded" files from the app. Just DON'T push node_modules. That is the way.

Comment: You are right. The issue is that node_modules got removed from local repo (I don't expect it to be in remote as it is ignored).

Comment: is it reproducible? if you push again, does it disappear again?

Comment: Nope, can't seem to reproduce it again.